# AngularJS : Sharing a controller scope between two directives with isolate scopes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I have two directives that provide different views on the same set of data. Both of these directives need to rely on central functionality contained in a controller. The controller uses various services to load items, perform searches, etc for the grid or feed views.

I would like to share the single controller between the two directives. I realize that I can do this by specifying the controller at a level in the dom above the two directives using ng-controller. However, I cannot get this to work, as both of the directives require a configuration object being passed into them (preferably through an isolate scope) which is used by the central controller.

I cannot simply specify the controller within each directive because angularjs controllers are not singletons. By doing this, there would be two instances of the controller and therefore two sets of data, watches, etc.

Below is an example situation.

HTML

```
<!-- myConfigObject comes from a scope above ListingController -->
<div data-ng-controller="ListingController">
    <div data-dir1 data-config="myConfigObject"></div>
    <div data-dir2 data-config="myConfigObject"></div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
.controller('ListingController',
    function ($scope) {
        //Try to use $scope.config here and get errors because it's being passed in on 
        //children dom elements

        //These items need to be used in the templates provided in the directives sharing
        //this controller
        $scope.items = [
            {name:'test1'},
            {name:'test2'}
        ];
    }
);
```

Directives:

```
.directive('dir1',
    function() {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'someTemplateThatUsesStuffOnControllerScope.html',
            scope: {
                config: '='
            }
        }
    }
)
.directive('dir2',
    function() {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'someOtherTemplateThatUsesStuffOnControllerScope.html',
            scope: {
                config: '='
            }
        }
    }
)
```

someTemplateThatUsesStuffOnControllerScope.html

```
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Finally, I'm wanting to use isolate scopes so as to protect other parent scopes from having a possible "$scope.config" overridden by the directives'

Hopefully that all makes sense to someone and hopefully there is an answer out there.

Comment: Have you asked a question or gave a solution from your scenario????

Comment: Comments on the only answer below

Comment: Can you be more clear??

Comment: Can you tell me which parts are unclear and I will try to expand upon them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a common controller for both directives. The following example creates two isolated directive that uses a common controller called **ControllerOfDir1Dir2**.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope){}]);

app.directive('dir1', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<div>Sample text of dir1</div>',
        scope: {},
        link: ControllerOfDir1Dir2
    };
});

app.directive('dir2', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<div>Sample text of dir2</div>',
        scope: {},
        link: ControllerOfDir1Dir2
    };
});

function ControllerOfDir1Dir2(scope, element, attr){
    // You can get the node name (dir1 or dir2) using element[0].nodeName
    var existingHtml = element.html();
    element.find('div').html(existingHtml + " And some added text");
}
```

Comment: So first, I was hoping to not have to do something like "getDataForDirX(...)". That gives ListingController knowledge of the two children elements. I was trying to keep it generic. The controller holds the data and offers methods that the children directives can use.

Comment: Second, I thought I mentioned it above, but the ListingController uses some of the things passed in through the config object to the two directives. In essence, I am wanting a single controller and for it to share a scope with the two children directives.

Comment: Hi, I modified my example, please have a look.

Comment: Hi SM, Your latest example isn't actually using a controller. It is passing a defined function as the link for both directives. This does not solve the problem, as any data that is defined or retrieved within that function will be done twice (once for each directive).

Comment: For each directive, the corresponding link/controller will be called once. Looks like we need to go beyond angular to do this :)

Comment: Another issue, if angular fires one controller function for two or more directives then how we will work with elements and attributes? Then we will need the array of element or attribute, which is not supported by angular.

Comment: SM, it is likely that what I am wanting to do is not supported by angular. It seems like it should, but maybe it doesn't. I am essentially wanting the user to toggle between a grid view and a list view on the same data. The best way that I could think to accomplish this was by having a central controller that retrieves the data, etc. Then have two directives for the two views. One is hidden and one is shown.